# Moving pointer from main() to first executable function

Tags: c, pointers, deque

is there any way to move pointer, which is initialized in `main()` function, to first executable function and have it accessible in whole program?

Here's the code:

main function, where is pointer `d` initialized:

```
void main(){
    int x;
    deque *d;
    d=(deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));
    initDeque(d);
```

and I want to move the pointer into function called `initDeque()`

```
void initDeque(deque *d){ //Create new deque
    d->front=NULL;
    d->rear=NULL;
}
```

Is it possible to move it?

Comment: why cant you just move the malloc to initDeque() function?

Comment: The pointer is *copied*, but the copy in `initDequeu`  points to the same memory as `d` in the `main` function. So it should work well as written currently. Do you mean that you want to have the declaration of the pointer in the `initDeque` function? Then just have the function *return* the pointer. Also, [don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: and don't use sizeof(type) inside malloc, but sizeof object.  `d = malloc(sizeof *d);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "move the pointer" you mean that you want to move the variable declaration, then you can do that but it will become a local variable only accesible inside that function. Clearly not what you want.

You need to make it global, that will make it accessible from all scopes. Note that global variables are considered ugly and increase the risk of errors and generally make the code less clear.

With a global pointer it would look like this:

```
deque *d;

void initDeque(void)
{
  d = malloc(sizeof *d);
  d->front = d->rear = NULL;
}
```

Note that you [shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Also note that *nobody* would have a global variable named using a single lower-case letter. It's *way* to easy to confuse it with a local variable, so you should *at least* make the name more obvious, e.g. something like

```
deque *theDeque;
```

Comment: Yeah, I've done similar to what you described above.
 `deque* initDeque(){ //Create new deque
    deque* d = (deque*)malloc(sizeof(deque));
    d->front=NULL;
    d->rear=NULL;
    return d;
}
`
and in `main` i've done this: `deque *d = initDeque();` . Is there any easier way, than creating global variable?

Comment: If you want to access in whole program, why a global is disturbing you ?

Comment: @AurélienLAJOIE Because it's risky. Any code anywhere can do something "bad" with the global, there is no encapsulation.

Comment: @unwind _G is only visible into the file, not anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Create a static structure to store all you want share.
Create a function to allocate your deque. I don't know the size of deque perhaps you can take it on the stack instead of the heap.

```
static struct {
   deque d*;
} _G;

void main(){
    int x;
    _G.d = deque_new();
}

deque *deque_new(void){
    deque *d;

    d = malloc(sizeof(deque));
    d->front=NULL;
    d->rear=NULL;
    return d;
}
```

or with the stack

```
static struct {
   deque d;
} _G;

void main(){
    int x;
    deque_init(&_G.d);
}

deque *deque_init(deque *d){
    memset(d, 0, sizeof(*deque)); 
    return d;
}
```

Comment: The code in `deque_new()` is using an undefined `d`.